# cordova requirements Android target: not installed

Tags: java, android, cordova

Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle

Requirements check results for browser:
(node:18240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
(node:18240) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097394/2642351 try installing JDK version less than 9, like JDK8

Comment: I run java 1.8-152 and I still experience this problem.

Comment: Confirm if your cordova version is latest. You can also try to read the documentation for that version to know which version of Java is it compatible with.

Comment: Well I can't upgrade cordova so we locked it at 6.2.2 ; but the problem shouldn't be bound to this version as we also didn't update Android version and everything was working fine says, two weeks ago.



We did a test on my laptop by creating a separate project, even with latest cordova / android sdk version, we still get the same error.

Comment: Then I guess your Java version might have updated between these 2 weeks. Just downgrade the version to the previous one. Or goto Cordova and find the Java version compatible for the version that you have and install it. That should fix

Comment: If this helped vote up the comments and the answer please

Comment: Didn't see your answer until now. I just checked, my Java version is still the same as previous weeks, aka 1.8.0_152.